# Row columns does not fill container

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I've one container with two rows inside. One of that rows has some columns. What I would like to do is have on mobile four columns per line. And that works fine with "row-cols-4". But for big screen, I would like to have all the columns on the same line, so I used "row-cols-md-auto" to do that. The problem is that the row does not fill the container as you can see in the image below:

[image]

I'm using Bootstrap v5.2 and this is a snippet of my code:

```
<div class="container text-center bg-white">
    <div id="menu" class="row row-cols-4 row-cols-md-auto sticky-top mt-5">
        <button id="faq1" class="col p-2 p-md-3 border" href="#">FAQ1</button>
        <button id="faq2" class="col p-2 p-md-3 border" href="#">FAQ2</button>
        <button id="faq3" class="col p-2 p-md-3 border" href="#">FAQ3</button>
        <button id="faq4" class="col p-2 p-md-3 border" href="#">FAQ4</button>
        <button id="faq5" class="col p-2 p-md-3 border" href="#">FAQ5</button>
        <button id="faq6" class="col p-2 p-md-3 border" href="#">FAQ6</button>
        <button id="faq7" class="col p-2 p-md-3 border" href="#">FAQ7</button>
        <button id="faq8" class="col p-2 p-md-3 border" href="#">FAQ8</button>
    </div>
    <div id="viewer" class="row">
        <div class="include-html"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

What can I do to fill the container on the desktop screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `row-cols-md-auto` will make the columns (buttons) shrink to the width of their content. Also Bootstrap doesn't offer a `row-cols-md` class to make the columns grow width on medium viewport size. Therefore, I don't think is possible using row-cols-*. Instead you could use a custom CSS class...

CSS...

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .row-cols-md>.col {
        flex: 1 0 0%;
    }
}
```

markup...

```
<div class="container text-center bg-white">
    <div id="menu" class="row row-cols-4 row-cols-md sticky-top mt-5">
        <button id="faq1" class="col p-2 p-md-3 border" href="#">FAQ1</button>
        <button id="faq2" class="col p-2 p-md-3 border" href="#">FAQ2</button>
        <button id="faq3" class="col p-2 p-md-3 border" href="#">FAQ3</button>
        <button id="faq4" class="col p-2 p-md-3 border" href="#">FAQ4</button>
        <button id="faq5" class="col p-2 p-md-3 border" href="#">FAQ5</button>
        <button id="faq6" class="col p-2 p-md-3 border" href="#">FAQ6</button>
        <button id="faq7" class="col p-2 p-md-3 border" href="#">FAQ7</button>
        <button id="faq8" class="col p-2 p-md-3 border" href="#">FAQ8</button>
    </div>
    <div id="viewer" class="row">
        <div class="include-html"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

### OR

You can avoid the custom CSS and not use row-cols-*. Instead use the class grid sizes...

```
<div class="container text-center bg-white">
    <div id="menu" class="row sticky-top mt-5">
        <button id="faq1" class="col-md col-3 p-2 p-md-3 border" href="#">FAQ1</button>
        <button id="faq2" class="col-md col-3 p-2 p-md-3 border" href="#">FAQ2</button>
        <button id="faq3" class="col-md col-3 p-2 p-md-3 border" href="#">FAQ3</button>
        <button id="faq4" class="col-md col-3 p-2 p-md-3 border" href="#">FAQ4</button>
        <button id="faq5" class="col-md col-3 p-2 p-md-3 border" href="#">FAQ5</button>
        <button id="faq6" class="col-md col-3 p-2 p-md-3 border" href="#">FAQ6</button>
        <button id="faq7" class="col-md col-3 p-2 p-md-3 border" href="#">FAQ7</button>
        <button id="faq8" class="col-md col-3 p-2 p-md-3 border" href="#">FAQ8</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Demo: https://codeply.com/p/1B1abfyZ0q

Answer (score -2):

[image]

Check also for div and your container class.

```
<>
<>Your Code</>
</>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, but I don't understand how it can help me.  My problem is not about the creation of grid system but, as you can see on my posted image, about "row-cols-*-auto" that doesn't fill the container space.